# Salesforce to Xero integration

Tags: api, integration

I need a step by step guide into setting up an integration between Salesforce and Xero. I'm asking those who have tried integrations with Quickbooks or other applications if you have experience with this and please share your thoughts.

Regards,

Pfang

Comment: I have done integration with Quickbooks. How it will helpful in integration with Xero? @Phil

Comment: How did you start, do you have a step by step guide?

Comment: Start with provided documentation, if you face problem regarding integration you can post here. Currently your question it too wide to explain.

Comment: I was given these for starters but I need something more basic in terms of integration. How do you start with your integration? What do you download? What language do you study? What tools do you get?

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index.htm
 
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/

https://www.salesforce.com/assets/pdf/misc/06.2328_WP_ApexConnect_2.pdf

http://www.salesforce.com/assets/pdf/datasheets/DS_DEV502.pdf

Comment: 1) What language did you use for Quickbooks and Salesforce?

2) Did you create an application or was it an online integration?

3) What resources were you using as reference? Tutorials, videos, etc.

4) I read about different ways to integrate, PHP, API, REST, SOAP, I'm not sure which one to start with or use?

5) Do you have documentation of how you did this, can I borrow it and use it as reference for my methodology?

Comment: Appreciate your help reddev

Comment: Well I tried to provide answers to you query. Hope it help. You are asking something which is generally not to share.

Answer (score 2):

Answers:

1) Apex and some visualforce pages required only.

2) It was an online integration and live somewhere on platform as an Appexchange application. However An standalone application can be possible.

3) Documentation provided by Quickbook, some efforts in collecting things together. Initially Quickbook documentaion was used.

4) I tried it with REST API and succeed. Uses OAuth 1.0 flow. (Not sure about xerox)

5) I have but cannot share in public.

Except these if you are doing first time, you may need to some study about authentication procedures used by your third party application (Xerox). I suggest to start with understanding authentication process.

Comment: Very informative. A basic step by step guide is what I'm looking for. If you can provide something like this without specifics, general practice for integration, it will help me get things rolling.

Comment: Hi @reddev 
 Im also integration at salesforce to xero using REST API please send me the link regarding quickbook for this integration which you have followed and succeeded this integration process.

Answer (score 1):

A native apex library for Xero is provided on the Appexchange

http://tinyurl.com/dimefordev

This handles all OAuth 1.0a interactions and provides apex methods for each Xero endpoint

Comment: Looking into that Dan, had Dime installed a few days ago and I'm trying custom field mapping but they don't have it for the version I installed.

Comment: Looking at this too

Comment: Dime for CRM is a product with fixed field mappings.

Comment: Dime for Developers allows you to set the exact field mappings you require (via apex code)

Comment: Hi Dan, will this allow automated batch record syncing. I mean I create several records in Salesforce, around a hundred, schedule a sync with Xero at a certain interval?

Comment: Yes just make sure you use a Salesforce batch size that ensures you don't make more than 10 http callouts per execution as per Salesforce limits

Comment: Hi Dan, will Dime allow this and are you referring to REST API?

Comment: I'm referring to Salesforce limits. In this case "Total number of callouts (HTTP requests or Web services calls) in a transaction" as referred to here - http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm - Dime is using standard Salesforce http callouts to Xero and therefore constrained by the limits Salesforce imposes